# Nested list and sorting in python

Tags: python, sorting, nested-lists

I don't know if it is possible or not. I am trying to find a way of sorting a nested list on the following condition

1. i want to sort form 1 point to another (NOT the whole list only part of it)
2. the sorting should be done on the basis of 3rd element of the sublists

an Idea of what i want:

```
    PAE=[['a',0,8],
         ['b',2,1],
         ['c',4,3],
         ['d',7,2],
         ['e',8,4]]

    #PAE[1:4].sort(key=itemgetter(2))  (something like this)    
    or    
    #sorted(PAE[1:4],key=itemgetter(2))  (something like this)  
`   # ^ i know both are wrong but just for an idea
`
    #output should be like this  
    ['a', 0, 8]
    ['b', 2, 1]
    ['d', 7, 2]
    ['c', 4, 3]
    ['e', 8, 4]
```

I am new to python, but i tried my level best to find a solution but failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort the slice **and write it back**:

```
>>> PAE[1:4] = sorted(PAE[1:4], key=itemgetter(2))
>>> PAE
[['a', 0, 8], ['b', 2, 1], ['d', 7, 2], ['c', 4, 3], ['e', 8, 4]]
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do :

```
from operator import itemgetter
PAE=[['a',0,8],
    ['b',2,1],
    ['c',4,3],
    ['d',7,2],
    ['e',8,4]]

split_index = 1

print PAE[:split_index]+sorted(PAE[split_index:],key=itemgetter(2))
#=> [['a', 0, 8], ['b', 2, 1], ['d', 7, 2], ['c', 4, 3], ['e', 8, 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

here without spliting, question is whats is the best for readability

```
PAE=[['a',0,8],
    ['b',2,1],
    ['c',4,3],
    ['d',7,2],
    ['e',8,4]]

print (sorted(PAE, key=lambda PAE: PAE[1] if not PAE[1] else PAE[2]))
>>> [['a', 0, 8], ['b', 2, 1], ['d', 7, 2], ['c', 4, 3], ['e', 8, 4]]
```

Comment: I don't think it answers the question. Your sort depends on the second element of each list, right?

Comment: NO Eric, the sort key is relative in this case

Comment: Yes, but the question didn't mention it.

Comment: Let the OP decide. It matches the expectation for this exact example. But wouldn't work with `['a', 1, 8]` as the first list.

Comment: Thank you for for trying Ari :) , but as Eric mentioned its for one particular case. But i wanted, is a generalized solution.  Check Stephan and Eric's solutions both worked perfectly.

Comment: yes but i hate spliting or indexing stuff, its hardcoding.... i am looking for a answer without index,split